# Searching the current working directory and retrieving all of the files in a list in ascending order of the number at the end of the file name

Tags: python

I have the following list of files in my current working directory:

```
Java_question_1.txt

Java_question_2.txt 

Java_question_3.txt
```

and so on ...

I want to search the current working directory and retrieve all of these file objects / names in a list in ascending order of the number at the end of the file name.

Also, I want to perform a check to ensure that they are actually .txt (or possibly some other file extension, like .bin or .dat. So, if we have

```
Java_question_1.txt

Java_question_3.txt 

Java_question_3.dat

Java_question_4.txt
```

and so on, it would only get the .txt files (or the .dat files, if I so choose).

I was thinking of something like this:

```
if (language == "Java"):
    path = os.getcwd()
    print("path is: " + path)
    files = []
    for j in range(1, NUMBER_OF_JAVA_QUESTIONS_AVAILABLE + 1):
        for i in os.listdir(path):
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, i)) and 'Java_question_' in i:
                files.append(i)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
import os
language = "Java"  # The language to which the questions belongs to
file_type = "txt"  # The required file extension
files = []  # The list to store all the file paths

path = os.getcwd()  # Getting into current working directory
for i in os.listdir(path):
    # Traversing through all the file paths in the directory
    if i.startswith(language) and i.endswith(file_type):
        # Checking if the file belongs to the language and the extension which we require
        files.append(i)  # Saving the file

files.sort()  # Sorting files
print(files)
```

All files in the directory:

```
Java_question_1.txt Java_question_2.txt Java_question_3.txt Java_question_4.dat Java_question_4.txt main.py
```

Output:

```
['Java_question_1.txt', 'Java_question_2.txt', 'Java_question_3.txt', 'Java_question_4.txt']
```